# Crear Tabla con dos Listas en Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Hola soy nueva en Thymeleaf, tengo dos lista que envió desde mi controlador a una plantilla thymeleaf, mi pregunta puedo usar esas dos listas y mostrarlas en una tabla.

Lista 1 tiene: id, name, key
lista 2 tiene: id, id_lista1 y key

Lo que deseo obtener es una tabla que se muestre:

name_lista1 key_lista1 key_lista2

```
<div class="ac-content">
    <table class="aui" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="basic-number">#</th>
                    <th id="basic-fecha">Fecha</th>
                    <th id="basic-lname">Name</th>
                    <th id="basic-key">Key</th>
                    <th id="basic-keyI">Key Issue</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:if="${Lista_P.empty}">
                    <td colspan="2"> No hay Proyectos Disponibles </td>
                </tr>
                <th:block th:each="iss : ${Lista_I}"  th:if="iss.id_project == pro.id"  > 
                <tr th:each="pro : ${Lista_P}">   

                        <td headers="basic-number">#</td>
                        <td headers="basic-fecha"><span th:text="${fecha}"> Fecha </span></td>
                        <td headers="basic-lname"><span th:text="${pro.name}"> Name </span></td>
                        <td headers="basic-key"><span th:text="${pro.key}"> Key </span></td>
                        <td headers="basic-keyI"><span th:text="${iss.key}"> Key Issue </span></td>

                </tr>
                </th:block>
            </tbody>
        </table>            
 </div>
```

Comment: Podrías publicar lo que has intentado para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: ya publique parte del código.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, cambiando  <tr th:each = "pro : ${Lista_P}" th:if="${iss.id_project == pro.id}">